# redirect to jsp page using jsp code only

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, jsp-tags

I am trying to redirect to another jsp page using Jsp code only.

**index.jsp**

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>Testing</title>
         <script>
         function vali()
         {
            var name= document.for.name.value;
             if(name!="")
             {
                 window.location.("page2.jsp");
             }
             else{
                 alert("enter name");
             }
         }
         </script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <form name="for">
         <table>
             <tr><td>Enter name:</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="name" value=""></td>
             </tr>
             <tr><td>
                 <input type="button" value="click" onclick="vali()">
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
             </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

**page2.jsp**

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>   
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>Page2 welcomes u</h1>
     </body>
</html>
```

This code working perfectly fine , but i am trying to do it only by jsp without using javascript.

I have tried

```
    <%
         String name = request.getParameter("name");
          if(name!=null){
               response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");
         }

    %>
```

but its not working , It redirects page as soon as page loads.
Please help with some code

Answer (score 0):

Use "form name='for' action='page2.jsp'" and button submit redirect the page

Answer (score 0):

you have to just put into jquery/javascript

window.location.href = "page2.jsp"
or
in form action parameter value need to set

and change button type submit.

or give form to id and document.getelementbyid(formid).submit();

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your index.jsp:

```
     <%
        if( request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            if( name != null && name.length() != 0 )
                response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");
            else    
    %>
                <script>
                    alert("enter name please");
                </script>
    <%
        }

    %>
```

And also change your form like this

```
<form method="post">
     <table>
         <tr><td>Enter name:</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="name" value=""></td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td>
             <input type="submit" value="click">
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
         </form>
```

Comment: thank you , i think you have understood my problem , but your code is not working (i have added the '{' in else section)

Comment: @BlindCoder I've checked the code it working. please use it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Below code :

```
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Testing</title>
<script>
    function vali() {
        var name = document.for.name.value;
        if (name != "") {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("enter name");
            return false
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="for" action="page2.jsp" onsubmit="return vali();">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="click"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i have call validate function on form submit which will return true or false base on validation.it submit form only if function return true.Here Javascript is just used for validation.

Comment: thank you, that help me a lot , but i want to do it without using javaScript

Comment: How you validate data without javascript?Here javascript just validate data.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%=request.getRequestDispatcher("<path to another page>").forward(request, response)%>
```

on the action from where you want to forward to another page

After trying I get the code working without use of scriptlets

```
        <form name="for">
            <table>
                <tr><td>Enter name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" value=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="
                                window.location = 'page2.jsp'">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<%
     String name = request.getParameter("name");
      if(!name.equals("") || name.length() != 0){
           response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");
     }

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use 'action' in form tag. It's very simple.

```
<form action="page2.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here"/>
</form>
```

input type should be "submit" but you can change the value as you need.